# stat.checksum return value missing in ansible 2.2

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to find the checksum of a file in a playbook using the stat module.

```
 ---
   - name: loading checksum to variable
     stat: 
       path: /data/foo.256
       checksum_algorithm: sha256
     register: origin

   - debug:
     msg: "The checksum of the file is {{ origin.stat.checksum }}"
```

The error I get when I run the playbook is

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'checksum'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/data/playbooks/roles/test/tasks/main.yml': line 8, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - debug:\n    ^ here\n"}
```

I tried to get some more verbosity using `-vvv` to the play and i noticed that there is no checksum in the return values of the module.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "checksum_algorithm": "sha256", 
            "follow": false, 
            "get_checksum": true, 
            "get_md5": true, 
            "mime": false, 
            "path": "/data/foo.256"
        }, 
        "module_name": "stat"
    }, 
    "stat": {
        "atime": 1505250191.0, 
        "ctime": 1505250179.0, 
        "dev": 2057, 
        "executable": true, 
        "exists": true, 
        "gid": 0, 
        "gr_name": "root", 
        "inode": 5945, 
        "isblk": false, 
        "ischr": false, 
        "isdir": true, 
        "isfifo": false, 
        "isgid": false, 
        "islnk": false, 
        "isreg": false, 
        "issock": false, 
        "isuid": false, 
        "mode": "0755", 
        "mtime": 1505250179.0, 
        "nlink": 2, 
        "path": "/data/foo.256", 
        "pw_name": "root", 
        "readable": true, 
        "rgrp": true, 
        "roth": true, 
        "rusr": true, 
        "size": 4096, 
        "uid": 0, 
        "wgrp": false, 
        "woth": false, 
        "writeable": true, 
        "wusr": true, 
        "xgrp": true, 
        "xoth": true, 
        "xusr": true
    }
}
```

So, I re-ran the play using one of the return values displayed and the play seems to work successfully.

The version of ansible I am using is 2.2.0.0

```
  ansible 2.2.0.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see `"isdir": true`. Checksum is not displayed for directories.

Comment: Thanks! this was it. I forgot to mention the file in the path